# jquery: output pressed key to html

Tags: jquery, html, browser, shortcut

i want to listen for a key stroke, then output the pressed key into every span element inside class=letter element using jquery. **at the same time** i want to preserve basic functionality of the keyboard shortcuts native to the browser eg. *shift + cmd + ]; cmd + r; ctrl + tab* etc...

```
<div class="letter">
<span>a</span>
</div>
```

this jQuery works very well on detecting and outputing the keystrokes that i am after.

```
$(window).on("keypress", function (e) {
                var t = e.which || e.keyCode;
                if (e.which === 0 && e.keyCode > 0) return;
                    var n = String.fromCharCode(t);
                    $(".letter").find("span").html(n);

                e.preventDefault();
        });
```

now i need to exclude somehow the shortcuts but i want to keep the *e.preventDefault();* line as it's muting the "wrong button" sound...

Comment: What key press specifically are you trying to detect?

Comment: letters, numerals, anything accessible from keyboard that can be represented as a glyph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe all you need to do is detect the alt, ctrl and meta keys ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/vpCau/)):

```
$(window).on("keypress", function (e) {
    var t = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (e.which === 0 && e.keyCode > 0 || e.altKey || e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
        return;
    }
    var n = String.fromCharCode(t);
    $(".letter").find("span").html(n);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: i wanted to keep the alt functionality for sure so i left only ctrl and meta. works well! thank you!